# What are the specifications of the General Electric J85 engine compressor?

Tags: engine, compressor

On the internet I can't seem to find all the specifications I need.

Mostly I'm looking for the **tip** and **hub radius** and the **angular velocity** of the blades.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably going to be beyond the scope of most on this board.  If you really want an answer to this, I'd contact Thornton Aircraft Company in Van Nuys, CA (http://www.thorntonaircraft.com).  They deal in sales and maintenance on old T-38s and F-5s as well as do type ratings in the jets.  They are intimately familiar with the J-85 power plant and could probably supply you with that info.